# Mac Terminal command - Find string and print with surrounding line

Tags: grep, terminal, macintosh, ack

I have been testing using ack, sed, grep trying to search through files in a directory to find a particular string.  I am looking through my database files to check to see if passwords are listed in clear text.  So far, I have been able to use this command:  grep -Ri "search_string" /path_to_Folder

However, this only outputs the files that contain the string.  I want to go one step further and print out the line around the string so I don't have to go in and search each file.

I hope that make sense.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Does the grep on OS X have a -C option?

Comment: @JeffSchaller [Yes](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, to:

> print out the line around the string

you can use grep's `-C` (context) option, like so:

```
grep -aRi -C 1 "search_string" /path_to_Folder
```

which will print three lines for every match: the line before the match, the matching line, and the line after the match.

Since the database files were binary, we also need grep's -a flag, so that it treats files as text.

Sample run:

```
$ grep -aRi jeff *
a/b/c/i:jeff
a/b/i:jeff
a/i:jeff
i:jeff
```

vs

```
$ grep -aRi -C1 jeff *
a/b/c/i-hi
a/b/c/i:jeff
a/b/c/i-bye
--
a/b/i-hi
a/b/i:jeff
a/b/i-bye
--
a/i-hi
a/i:jeff
a/i-bye
--
i-hi
i:jeff
i-bye
```

Comment: Adding some `--color` is usually helpful, if your `grep` and terminal supports that.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jeff.  I tried that code and it once again tells me the files that match, but don't give me any print out of the matching line.  Here is an output.  I made 3 text files with the word "test" in it and placed them in a desktop folder.
administrator$ grep -Ri -C1 "test" /Users/administrator/Desktop/test\ Folder
 
Here is the output.....
Binary file /Users/administrator/Desktop/test Folder/test copy 2.txt matches
Binary file /Users/administrator/Desktop/test Folder/test copy.txt matches
Binary file /Users/administrator/Desktop/test Folder/test.txt matches

Comment: Ahh, I was afraid of that, but assumed that you were getting results previously, perhaps with flat-file "databases".

Comment: Does it help if you add the -a (or --text) flag to grep?

Comment: The -a definitely made a difference!  Thank you.  It started  outputting some helpful data from the database.  I think I can start to modify from there to pull accurate data.   Learn something new everyday.  Thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear; I've updated the answer accordingly.